# How To: Desktop as Server, Laptop as “Thin Client”?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, laptop, thin-client

I have a really fast gaming PC, I don’t use it for gaming, instead I use it for just really fast everyday tasks. I have a oldish laptop which is very slow.

The idea is that I want to be able to use my desktop as a "Server" for the laptop and only use the laptop almost as a remote control of sorts for the desktop.

Does anyone know of a creative solution or software that does something like this?

I also would like my PC to boot when I open the laptop and shutdown when I close the laptop.

Thank you

Astad

(Re-asking [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/456565/how-to-desktop-as-server-laptop-as-thin-client) for the modern view)

Comment: If you're running a Pro edition of Windows on the desktop, use Remote Desktop.

Comment: The original question doesn't really describe a "thin-client" scenario as they are traditionally described, so what you want is completely possible. the difficulty comes in when you try to use a very stripped down client. if you can just use a "lighter" OS on the laptop, like your average linux distro with a lightweight shell, then you shouldn't have much difficulty. Please tell us what OSes you wish to use on each end, and please understand, your question must consist of more than a request for software recommendations, as they are out of scope here.